# Mapping the column names in Python

Tags: python, database

My base file has 22 columns(first_name,last_name etc.) including an identifier.
There are multiple other files which I have to join with this base file and get the identifier. But these files do not have all the fields populated. ​
I'm trying to write a python function which joins the files based on the columns available in each file(with the help of metadata below)

| ---Filename----- | -----first_name--------- |----last_name----|---address1---|
| Account          | client_first_name        | client_last_name|              |
| Trans            | firstname                | lastname        |   address    |
| Cardholders      | firstname                |                 |              |

Comment: Honestly, you need a database.  Sqlite is included with Python and fully functional.  You could merge all of these files into an sqlite table and make things a lot easier.

Comment: This process is for loading these files into the database.

Comment: If you make example python code. Including two of your 'other files' set up as strings. Making sure you have samples that have a fileds not populated. And then show the output you want. Then it would be easy to get help with the logic. As it is, someone would have to spend too much time guessing at an example to test it.

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] including code for what you've tried so far based on your own research so that we can understand how best to help. This may be a perfect use case for the pandas library, but it's hard to know without knowing where you're starting from